# Detect the "outliers"

Tags: pandas, outliers

In a column I have values like 0.7,0.85, 0.45, etc but also it might happen to have 2.13 which is different than the majority of the values. How can I spotted this "outliers"?

Thank you

Comment: look up "z-score"

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call scipy.stats.zscore(a) with a as a DataFrame to get a NumPy array containing the z-score of each value in a. Call numpy.abs(x) with x as the previous result to convert each element in x to its absolute value. Use the syntax (array < 3).all(axis=1) with array as the previous result to create a boolean array. Filter the original DataFrame with this result.

```
z_scores = stats.zscore(df)

abs_z_scores = np.abs(z_scores)
filtered_entries = (abs_z_scores < 3).all(axis=1)
new_df = df[filtered_entries]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the standard deviation and mean of the set and remove anything more than X (say 2) standard deviations from the mean?

The following would calculate the standard deviation

```
 public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        double ret = 0;
        if (values.Count() > 1)
        {
            double avg = values.Average();
            double sum = values.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));
            ret = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (values.Count() - 1));
        }
        return ret;
    }
```